# How to automatically assign child taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, meta-tags

I'm building a virtual network like [Instagram](http://instagram.com/) but its contents (images) are about a certain event.  The strategy of selecting taxonomy terms is to display all of the tags (about 20 ones) and a checkbox and users can check any one of them. I use [ttr_configurable_widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/ttr_configurable_widget) to do so.

The problem is there are many synonyms for a word and I don't want to display the synonyms, as an example in tagging the words `female`, `women`, `girl`, `sister`, `daughter`, `lady` are almost the same so when some one search for `female` the `lady` tag should be searched as well, furthermore this tag should be displayed as a hidden element in the web page(for search engines)

So there is a main tag like `women` and a set of synonyms. What I need to do is to format the tags as follow

[image]

Then only display the `woman`, when a user selects `woman` its synonyms also be attached to the content.

It is also preferred to load the synonyms but hide them in the node display page.

How can I do this?

The [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) and [Taxonomy Group Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/tgf) are almost doing this but in these widgets users can check or uncheck the children even if the parent is selected.

[image]

Comment: Let them be loaded and hide with JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this job is using JQUERY,load all terms in the page  ,hide all of  children  terms and when the parent term checked show the children terms of it( also when unchecked hide all children of it).